# Why doesn't this work in Geogebra

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, math-software

I've got a really simple equation that I want [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/) to plot:

$\sqrt {2x}-\sqrt {3y} =2$

It says it's an illegal operation so I try:

$3y=2x-4\sqrt{2x}+4$

When this doesn't try, I try changing $\sqrt{2x}$ to $(2x)^{1/2}$ and it informs me that exponents can only be integers. Since when can't geogebra handle rational exponents?!

Comment: While GeoGebra can deal with a great many functions of a single variable, I believe it is much more limited when it comes to multi-variable expressions. Thus, while it can deal fine with `y=sqrt(x)` or `x^2+y^2=1`, it can't deal with `x^(1/2)+y^(1/2)=`1.

Comment: Well I wanted to plot to check my answer...Is there another program that can plot this that is easily available?

Comment: I don't know if geogebra can plot implicit equations, meaning you have to find just one variable in function of the others, say its $y= \text{expression in x} $, in this case geogebra can plot `f(x)=(expression)`

Comment: I tried with `f(x) = 1 / 3 (2x - 4sqrt(2x) + 4)`, it worked. Also I'd graph `g(x)=-f(x)` as well, then you'll be able to visualize the entire set of solutions

Comment: Could this be an error in my text book? I'm learning to find the slope and y-x intercepts.

Comment: Try Grafeq.  It can handle all kinds of odd equations...  It operates with the assumption of interval arithmetic, so you know exactly what the software is doing when it computes a graph.

Comment: Could what be an error?

Comment: Well if geogebra can't solve it then I'm guessing it's not so easy for a freshman. That's why I ask.

Comment: It's asking for the slope. I can't find this slope unless I implicitly differentiate the equation??

Comment: Oh god, the root is outside of the variables.....

Comment: I don't think the normal geogebra input solves equations, but CAS mode does. Press `ctrl+shift+K` to use CAS mode, type in your equation and press the solve button. It worked for me with this example so If you can't get it just ask and I'll try to help!

Comment: If you want to graph it, [desmos.com](http://www.desmos.com) is a nice online graphing calculator.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the GeoGebra manual](http://wiki.geogebra.org/en/ImplicitCurve_Command), currently the `ImplicitCurve[ <f(x,y)> ]` command only supports polynomials in $x$ and $y$.

> **ImplicitCurve[ < f(x,y)> ]**
>
> Creates the implicit curve f(x,y) = 0. Currently f(x,y) must be a polynomial in x and y.

Answer (score 0):

if geogebra can do parametric plot then you can try $$x = \dfrac{(t+2)^2}{2}, y = \dfrac{t^2}{3}, t \ge 0  $$

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in GeoGebra as a parametric plot (ie just abel's answer)

[http://web.geogebra.org/?command=Curve[(t+2)^2/2,t^2/3,t,0,20]](http://web.geogebra.org/?command=Curve[(t%2B2)%5E2/2,t%5E2/3,t,0,20])

The beta version can plot non-polynomials, hopefully being released soon:

http://web.geogebra.org/beta/?command=sqrt(2x)-sqrt(3y)=2

Answer (score 0):

The original equation in this thread now plots correctly as well as several others that previously would not plot such as $\ \sin (x+y) = x/y \ $.  Even simple ones like $ \ \sin y = x \ $ would not plot a year ago and now work with no problem.  Nice work GeoGebra.